# Decidability one relation, binary FOL over finite models

Tags: graph-algorithms, finite-model-theory

Suppose $\sigma$ is a vocabulary consisting of one binary relation $E$ and let $\phi$ be a $\sigma$ sentence. Is it decidable whether there is a finite directed graph $G$, with all in- and out-degrees $0$ or $1$, such that $G\models \phi$ ?

Comment: This is a very elementary question, and not of the level usually answered here.  Read any basic text on Finite Model Theory and you should know the answer.

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, a Q&A site for *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science* (TCS). Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in TCS. Please see the [FAQ] for more information on what is meant by this. Your question might be suitable for [cs.se] which has a broader scope.